# php explode file extension name giving null

Tags: php

So, when I upload files, i want to check which file extension it is:

```
$files      = $_FILES['files'];
```

[image]

```
$files_name      =  $files['name'];
```

Shows: `"img.jpg"'

```
$files_name_explode = end(explode('.', $files_name));
```

Getting `null`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It should work. See this : http://codepad.org/Nkx2KzMh

Comment: Your cord is correct. I think you should check again $file_name before explode. put var_dump($file['name']); before explode code. according to this code you should not get null if $file_name is not null

Comment: Okay. Sounds good. i will double check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code :

```
$path = $_FILES['files']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I made a mistake. I am getting null on the result.. :(

Comment: @RyanPicard  If this answer is working for you then please accept answer so, future user can review answer first.

Comment: For sure! =) Will do that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `explode` you can use `pathinfo`.

Use

```
$files_name_explode = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

`pathinfo()` can give you other information, such as canonical path, depending on the constant you pass to it.

Answer (score 1):

try this :full code to validate using in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)

```
if(isset($_FILES["file"]["type"])) 
{
    $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png","JPG");
    $temporary = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $file_extension = end($temporary);
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    ) && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 1000000)//Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
    && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
            //echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br/><br/>";
        }
        else
        {


    $file_name=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $rand_file_name=rand()."_".$file_name;

                $sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; // Storing source path of the file in a variable


                $targetPath = "../upload/". $rand_file_name; // Target path where file is to be stored
                move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath); // Moving Uploaded file                

        }
    }
    else
    {
        //echo "<span id='invalid'>***Invalid file Size or Type***<span>";
    }
}
```